# Three.js obj/mtl model is suddenly shown black

Tags: three.js, 3d, 3d-model

My three.js app used to work fine but when I tried the app today, the obj/mtl model is suddenly shown just black.

So this is how it used to look like:
[image]

But now it looks like this although I didn't change any code:
[image]

Here's my relevant code:

**HTML:**

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.js"></script>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
```

**Three.js:**

```
const scene = this.scene;
        const modelPath = 'assets/models/stereo/';
        const mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader.setCrossOrigin(true);
        mtlLoader.setPath(modelPath);
        mtlLoader.load("1281_HIFI_Stereo.mtl", function (materials) {
            materials.preload();
            const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            objLoader.setCrossOrigin(true);
            objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
            objLoader.setPath(modelPath);
            objLoader.load("1281_HIFI_Stereo.obj", function (object) {
                object.name = "stereo";
                object.position.set(0, -15, -60);
                object.rotation.set(0, THREE.Math.degToRad(-90), 0);
                scene.add(object);
            });
        });
```

You can see my full code from https://glitch.com/edit/#!/cuinjune-face-dj

I also tried using the old version of `OBJLoader.js` and `MTLLoader.js` but it still doesn't fix the problem.

What could be causing this issue and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like already mentioned at [GitHub](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/19903), you are mixing different versions of `three.js`.You are importing the latest versions of `OBJLoader` and `MTLLoader` but use the `three.js` main library from release `r110`.

Try it with these imports and it should work:

```html
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.110.0/build/three.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.110.0/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.110.0/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
```

Updated glitch: https://chain-efficacious-professor.glitch.me